# PowerBi Embedded Report is empty on mobile browers

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, powerbi, powerbi-embedded, power-bi-report-server

I have created a report with Power BI Desktop (October 2017), then I have saved it to a Power BI Server.

I am displaying the report in an iFrame, in an MVC Project, like this:

```
<div style="height:900px">
    <iframe src="http://192.168.0.20/reports/powerbi/util?rs:embed=true" allowFullScreen="true" style="overflow:hidden;height:100%;width:100%"></iframe>
</div>
```

The report displays correctly on a desktop browser, but when I enter from a mobile (Android or iOS), the report is blank (white).

Comment: Hi - In order to better help you, please report all of your mobile details:  os versions, browser versions, device details (Iphone 7, 7+, Samsung, etc). Thanks!

Comment: Hi Taterhead. I've tried from both Android and iOS, tried using Firefox/Chrome on Android and Safari on iOS. It seems to be a general issue :(

Comment: are these devices accessing your report server via your local network (I see 192.168....) or are they connecting in through the device cellular data/mobile network provider?  If via the mobile network, then perhaps they do not know how to reach the 192.168... ip address range ?  You need to change this iframe link to use the external facing address or DNS name.

Comment: The devices do not access the report directly. They access a website. That website has a report embedded. When I visit the website, AD credentials are required, I fill them in and the report is blank!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find it more useful to use Power BI Embedded directly,
this way you can embed it inside a  element in your website.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedding

You can even embed a mobile layout as authored in Power BI Desktop using only a single parameter in the load configuration:
https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Embed-For-Mobile

And create your own interactions with the JS SDK
https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/

Comment: That's what I did, eventually!